# Why does Jenkins hang when I try to build with the gradle-release plugin?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, grails3, gradle-release-plugin, gradle-3.0

I set up the release plugin on my Grails project and successfully ran it on my localhost.

When I try to set up the same build in Jenkins, the build hangs indefinitely. The last thing in the output before it hangs is the `checkCommitNeeded` step.

Anything I can do to figure out what's going wrong?

I have set `-Prelease.useAutomaticVersion=true` and the two version params in **switches**, as mentioned in the plugin docs.

**Update**

On the researchgate Gitter, Christian Gonzalez mentioned that Jenkins is detecting another commit caused by the release plugin, and getting itself stuck in a loop. For Git, an additional behavior can be added to ignore changes committed by the plugin. However, my project is using SVN.

**Update**

Below is a snippet of the output from adding -d

`11:12:48.907 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':checkCommitNeeded'.
11:12:48.908 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Running [svn, status] in [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyTeam/jobs/MyProject/jobs/MyProject-release/workspace]
11:12:48.924 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Running [svn, status] produced output: []
11:12:48.926 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':checkCommitNeeded'
11:12:48.926 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :checkCommitNeeded (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.02 secs.
11:12:48.926 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationWorkerRegistry] Worker root.3 completed (0 in use)
11:12:48.926 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationWorkerRegistry] Worker root.4 started (1 in use).
11:12:48.926 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :checkUpdateNeeded (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
11:12:48.927 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] :myproject:checkUpdateNeeded
11:12:48.927 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':checkUpdateNeeded'
11:12:48.927 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':checkUpdateNeeded' is up-to-date
11:12:48.927 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Executing task ':checkUpdateNeeded' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
11:12:48.927 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':checkUpdateNeeded'.
11:12:48.928 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Running [svn, status, -q, -u] in [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyTeam/jobs/MyProject/jobs/MyProject-release/workspace]
11:12:51.477 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:12:51.479 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:12:51.480 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:12:51.481 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:13:01.477 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:13:01.477 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:13:01.478 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:13:01.480 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:13:11.477 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:13:11.477 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:13:11.477 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:13:11.479 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
...`

The last 4 lines are repeated over and over.

Comment: Can you put -d to the task please. Then we will see the debug output of gradle

Comment: @Hillkorn Thanks! I added the debug output.

Comment: For the record, in my case, it appears to be an issue with the SVN CLI that the gradle plugin is using. Using the --no-daemon argument eliminated all of these noisy recurring messages and enabled us to see the actual root cause.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. For me, the reason was that I did the wrong setup configuration for the project. Example: wrong GitHub URL (without .git extension) added, incorrect Poll SCM config, etc.
Fix for me was to restart the Jenkins server & correct the changes under 'Manage' for your project & again build.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was due to a database table being locked. after killing the hanging sessions, it worked fine.